# R Reporting header

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ok,

R can easily add titles to plots. But what if we want a page title dead centre at top of page?

If we have 4 ggplots tiled on a page and want a pretty heading that says "GGplots" dead centre at the top of the page what's the quickest and easiest way to get this heading placed top centre?

Comment: use `outer = TRUE` in `title`, you may need to adjust `par(mgp = ...)`

Comment: Or add an Outer MArgin (oma) to the top like `par(oma=c(0,0,3,0))`, defining width of margin at bottom, left, top and right. Then write your title to that margin with `title(main = 'GGplots', outer = T)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, main="GGplots")
```

Comment: thank you for answer as it has opened a whole treasure chest of tools for me.  grid.text for modifying main above has many arguments, almost identical to those of textGrob, but what about color?  Is there a way to have main = "GGplots", color = "red") for example?

Comment: `textGrob('GGplots', gp=gpar(col="red"))`